# Reveal all duplicate items and highlight latest version based on data attributes

Tags: jquery

I'm not a jquery expert and some help would be appreciated if it's actually possible to do.

Please see my demo fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/jre166d1/

On this fiddle I have 23 images displayed in a gallery grid format using html figure markup.

In this array of images, there are 2 images that have duplicates. The images are `IMG 019` and `IMG 013`. I've also marked them with a duplicate data attribute for testing reference.

Using a `button`, when clicked, I want to add a class called `.duplicate` to the `FIGURE` item based on the data attribute called `data-title`.

The `data-title` value is the key to check wether there are any duplicates.

Once this check has been made, I want to add class called `.latest-duplicate` to the latest uploaded image in the duplicates result. There is data attribute called `data-time` with a standard php date string `2016-12-19 13:09:37` which would be the key to find out the latest image.

So the idea is that all images that have a duplicate have a red background, but in those results, the latest duplicate has a green background. This is so the user can tell which duplicate is latest version.

I have no idea where to start so if anyone has any pointers that would be amazing thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/jre166d1/

```
// reveal duplicated images and highlight latest version
$('#reveal-duplicates').on('click', function() {

  // help
  ...

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#reveal-duplicates').on('click', function() {

  // do stuff
 $('figure').each(function(){
 var $this = $(this),
     title = $this.attr('data-title');

    var $foundFIgure = $('figure[data-title="'+title+'"]');
    if( $foundFIgure.length > 1 ){
        $foundFIgure.addClass('duplicate');
    }
 })

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jre166d1/4/

Comment: dude that is an awesome start, so clean. So length is just checking for any matches based to the title. Blows my mind. Do you think its possible to find the latest duplicate based on `data-time`?

Comment: Yes, it's easy. You need loop all figures to object || array. convert data-time to timestamp, and get count elements with data-title. After only need to sort